# I am using this Laravel Cart package olimortimer/laravelshoppingcart, where it's storing items in same cart for every users.using REST API

Tags: php, laravel, shopping-cart

HERE i am trying to make REST API's using the mentioned package but it doesn't seems working with API Can you point out if i am making mistake.

```
class CartController extends Controller
{
public function ShowCart(){
    
    $content = Cart::content();
    return response()->json(['success'=>'true','item-list'=>$content]);

}

public function AddItemToCart(Request $request,$id){
              
        $item = FoodItem::where('id',$id)->first();
        Cart::add($item->id,$item->item_name,1,$item->price, ['image' => $request->image ,   
    'extras' =>$request->extras,'attribute'=>$request->attributes,]);
    return response()->json(['success'=>'true']);

}

public function AddQuantity($rowId){
    $row = Cart::get($rowId);
    Cart::update($rowId,  $row->qty +1);
    return response()->json(['success'=>'true']);
}

public function SubstractQuantity($rowId){
    $row = Cart::get($rowId);
    Cart::update($rowId,$row->qty - 1);
    return response()->json(['success'=>'true']);
}

public function DiscardCart(){
  Cart::destroy();
  return response()->json(['success'=>'true']);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Your package is working with session and not a database. As far as I understand what you are trying to do, I would not use this package to make an API.

Comment: Thanks for the reply do you have any tips for me or Tutorial for me to make Cart restful API?

Comment: Not sure, I never had to do this. Just made some research and I found this: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-restful-shopping-cart I suggest you to have a look, It's probably a good start